# Is there a non-legacy application for Windows to read Xdebug profiling files ("cachegrind")?

Tags: windows, php, profiling

I've installed Xdebug with PHP on Windows 10. It produces a bunch of files named things like: `cachegrind.out.2693358`

The Xdebug website links to an old software called `QCacheGrind (KCacheGrind) Windows build` which hasn't been updated for 10 years (2013) and which constantly keeps crashing when I try to import the files, so it's useless.

I've also found several alternatives or forks which are *also* not updated for a very long time (~2015).

Is there a non-legacy program to view these files on Windows? Something well-maintained, nice and useful?

All I'm trying to do is to measure which parts of my PHP code are the slowest/most resource-intense, by getting some kind of "heat map" or even just a text list of the top files/functions/line numbers in terms of time spent. But I can't find any software which doesn't crash silently when I try to open the files and which actually gives some sort of useful analysis!